# Passing Model to View

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, view, model

So I'm passing the following view model to my view, but the view is throwing an exception everytime it I try to visit the page. Any explanation as to why this is happening would be great, pointers on how to fix it would be better! Thanks.

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
MyCompareBase.Models.CategoryIndex', but this dictionary requires a model item 
of type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyCompareBase.Models.CategoryIndex]'.
```

View Model

```
public class CategoryIndex
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Categories")]
    public IEnumerable<string> CategoryNames { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<MyCompareBase.Models.CategoryIndex>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

  @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryNames)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var localDb = db.Categories.Select(c => c.Name);
        var wcf = category.Categories().Select(c => c.Name);

        var all = new HashSet<String>(localDb);
        all.UnionWith(wcf);

        var viewModel = new Models.CategoryIndex
        {
            Title = "Avaliable Product Categories",
            CategoryNames = all.AsEnumerable()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending single `CategoryIndex` object to view, but your view expects `IEnumerable<CategoryIndex>.`

Comment: Thank you for the help, still new to .Net but I've sorted it out.

Answer (score 0):

Valin is right that you need to pass IEnumerable. You can modify your code as:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var localDb = new List<string>{"a", "b"};
    var wcf = new List<string>{"b","c"};

    var all = new HashSet<String>(localDb);
    all.UnionWith(wcf);

    var viewModel = new List<CategoryIndex>
    {
        new CategoryIndex
            {
                Title = "Avaliable Product Categories",
                CategoryNames = all.AsEnumerable()
            }
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```